# How to test local storage persistence after iOS App Store update?

Tags: ios, air, adobe, local-storage, shared-objects

At one point there was an [AIR bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3347676) (3.5) that changed the location of the LSO storage, causing local `SharedObject`s to be "lost" after an app update. Apparently this issue was resolved in 3.6 and life goes on.

At this point I don't have 100% confidence that any user data stored in a SharedObject on an iOS device will persist after an AppStore update, and I would like to be able to test this out prior to actually submitting the update to Apple.

However, my experience has been than whenever you test/debug your app and a new IPA is generated, the old app is completely wiped, including all of its data. So there's no way that I know of that I can test an update of the app against an older version to ensure that the SharedOjbects remain accessible and working fine.

Are there any solutions? Or can anyone who's using LSO for persistent App data storage confirm that they've pushed an update through the App Store and retained saved user data?

Comment: The old app and ipa/apk files will be wiped out, but not the `SharedObject`. If this doesnt work for you, try writing [the data in a text file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @cforcloud. I agree that writing out the data explicitly is good: my problem is that the current app in the AppStore used SharedObject and now I'm afraid to issue an update!